# Overlay Density Curve on stacked geom_col plot? [code & images included]

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

```
# Creating overlayed barchart with ggplot 
dist_plot_prom_delv_Mon <-  ggplot(union_df_prom_delv_Mon,aes(x=Promise,y=Orders,fill=Flag)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha= .50, show.legend = FALSE)+
  theme_economist()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,30,1))+
  xlab("Promise & Delv Days") +
  ylab("Count of Orders") +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("sandybrown", "cadetblue4"))+
  ggtitle("E2E Promise & Delv Distribution Comparison 2020 YTD - Monday Orders")+
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12), axis.text=element_text(size=11), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=11), strip.text = element_text(size=11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 15, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

I currently have a "histogram" that I created by doing an overlayed bar chart using geom_col and using fill to make it seem like the data is overlayed. **See the current image below**
[image]

I want to overlay an additional layer which would be the density line with a low alpha similar to this **image.**
[image]

I had to use geom_col to mimic geom_histogram becuase geom_histogram was calculating my measure incorrectly. Here is a sample of my data and what gets overlayed.
[image]

```
dist_plot_prom_delv <-  ggplot(union_df_prom_delv,aes(x=Promise,y=Orders,fill=Flag)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha= .50, show.legend = FALSE)+
  theme_economist()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,30,1))+
         geom_density(fill="darkgrey", alpha=0.3)+
  xlab("Promise & Delv Days") +
  ylab("Count of Orders") +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("sandybrown", "cadetblue4"))+
  ggtitle("E2E Promise & Delv Distribution Comparison 2020 YTD ")+
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12), axis.text=element_text(size=11), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=11), strip.text = element_text(size=11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 15, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0)))




plot_prom2_Mon <- step1_fix %>% 
  rename(Promise = E2E_PROMISE_DAYS) %>% 
  group_by(Promise) %>% 
  filter(ORD_DOW == 'Monday') %>% 
  summarise(Orders = n_distinct(ORD_TRACK_KEY)) %>% 
  mutate(Flag = "Promise")

# Creating Logic to create union for overlayed bar chart 
plot_delv2_Mon <- step1_fix %>% 
  rename(Promise = E2E_BUS_DAYS) %>% 
  group_by(Promise) %>% 
  filter(ORD_DOW == 'Monday') %>% 
  summarise(Orders = n_distinct(ORD_TRACK_KEY)) %>% 
  mutate(Flag = "Delv")

# Creating union to create overlayed barchart
union_df_prom_delv_Mon <- union_all(plot_prom2_Mon, plot_delv2_Mon)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for adding a transparent area:

```
geom_area(aes(color=Fill), alpha=0.3, position="identity") +
theme(legend.position = "none") #for deleting the legend
```

Comment: thanks! I am getting the following error: geom_density requires the following missing aesthetics: y

Comment: Please update your data as code so i can see what's happening

Comment: I meant post the dataset as code, you posted a print screen of `union_df_prom_delv_Mon`, but in order to run code with it we need it as text. Use `dput(union_df_prom_delv_Mon)` or `dput(union_df_prom_delv_Mon[1:20,])` if its too big.

Comment: sure posted above

Comment: last three blocks, sorry idk why it didnt break out into another code chunk

Comment: No problem, but that's not exactly it yet. In order to answer, we need to have the important part of your code, and (perhaps a subset of) the data that your code uses. It normally isn't important how your data was obtained, i only need the actual numbers of it to run code with, try using the `dput` function, that outputs your data as text that you can copy and paste here. For mor tips on how to write a good question, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: ahh I see, the data is a bit sensitive. Is there a work around for this

Comment: If it helps, you can omit the column names with `colnames(df)=NULL`.

Comment: okay I did the dput in my rconsole where do I share it with you?

Comment: Ideally in the post, the same way you added those chunks, but if you don't want to do that i can create a chat room and you send it there

Comment: sure if you could please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223456/discussion-between-ricardo-semiao-e-castro-and-jaskeil).

Comment: You want a density for each group or a mean density for both groups?

Comment: each group if you could

Comment: Ok then check the chat